# Can I create a session login by django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

basically, I want to allow an anonymous user to login to the website and not create a profile, but can save the session if wants, and revisit anytime

Answer (score 1):

you can use django sessions.
You could use something like ...

```
from datetime import datetime
```

When they log in use this to start the session.

```
request.session['user'] = datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

Then to check if the current user has a session go like this

```
if resquest.session.get('user'):
    # then continue the session
```

if you want to end their session use

```
 del request.session['user']
```

in installed apps in settings.py  you need.

```
'django.contrib.sessions',
```

In your middleware you need

```
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
```

So you need to check if there is a session started and if not start one.
For example in your home view or any other view at the start of the view for example you could have

```
if resquest.session.get('user'):
    # Do whatever you need to do to continue the current session
else:
    request.session['user'] = datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")
    # Now you have started a new session. start doing what you need to do
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand it now but I can't find the login function in my app

Comment: Is it only anonymous  users or users with a profile also?

Comment: Only anonymous users

Comment: if its only anonymous users you dont need a login function. just check for a session in every view that is called from the front end. Ill update my awnswer a little